# Force prettyPhoto to refresh when content changes dynamically

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, prettyphoto

i have [chained selects](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) that load images thumbnails linked with prettyphoto.

Obviously prettyphoto during initialization can see only the first select of the chain, so i should reinitialize it every time selects load the links!
i tried to call those scripts onchange trigger:

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
```

or

```
prettyPhoto.initialize();
```

but no one of them work.
The first gives no hints, the second returns me the error:  prettyPhoto is not defined!

All other images not loaded dinamically works fine, please help!

Answer (score 1):

i was wrong using `$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']")` selector in my page, but the first line of code is the right way to refresh prettyphoto script.

this is a simple example of this script works

Select:

```
<select name="option" onchange="pprefresh()">
    <option value="">select option</option>
    <option value="1">Option ONE!</option>
    <option value="2">Option TWO!</option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Loaded Image:

```
<a href="mysite.com/images/image.png" title="MyPhoto" rel="prettyPhoto" >
<img src="mysite.com/images/imagethumb.png"  />
</a>
```

Javascript PrettyPhoto Refresh:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    pprefresh();
});

function pprefresh(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
}
</script>
```